# Where can I find the corresponding documentation for the Rust target specification format?

Tags: rust

I'm building an application for `thumbv7em-none-eabihf` target.

I'd like to understand the field described in the JSON that I get when I run the following command:

```
rustc +nightly -Z unstable-options --print target-spec-json --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf
```

Where can I find the official corresponding documentation?

Comment: A note to those attempting to close the question: [Requests for an official resource are fine.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43207688#43207688) As long as we stick to canonical content, the question can become useful without becoming a source of rubbish.

Comment: @E_net4 I think a meta post is more authoritative than a link to a chat transcript; can you find one? Otherwise, that just appears to be Shog's opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_target/spec/index.html)

```
Struct rustc_target::spec::Target
Struct rustc_target::spec::TargetOptions
```

are the corresponding definitions.

Comment: @Tyfingr This is exactly what I was looking for. In the documetation of Target & TargetOptions I have listed all the possible values I can have in JSON as well as some brief info.